context free grammar to the language {^^^|1≤≤,1≤}
i need to create context free grammar to the language {^^^|1≤≤,1≤}
i need to save the order of the letter in each word and what was difficult to me was to ensure that n<=k.
i tried to solve this question like this:
S-\> ABC (ensures the order of the letter in the words)

A-\> aAbB|a

B-\> Bb|b

C-\> Cc|c

what changes i need to make to fit this grammer to my language?

$[S\to ABC;\ A\to aAb|ab;\ B\to Bb|\epsilon;\ C\to Cc|c]$ is one way.
